# drop down list keep previous selected value in php

Tags: php

I have created a profile page in php where a user using an html drop down list chooses gender.

The html code is the following:

```
Gender<select name="gender"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
    <option value="Male">Male</option> 
    <option value="Female">Female</option> 
</select>
```

After the user chooses gender the form dispatches and saves the data into database. All I want is that the next time that the user visits the profile page, the drop down list to keep the value that the user selected before. For example if user selected in drop down list "male", next time he visited profile page to make changes, the drop down list must show "male" as selected value(keeping it from previous time). Any idea how to do this in PHP?

Comment: you can use javascript to set option as selected.

Comment: I have tried the 2 answers that I get bellow... but stil not working

Comment: @Stefanos - What is the entirety of your code? Can you put it into a pastebin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is give the `selected` attribute to the option. Assuming you store profile information on the session and have short-tags enabled on your server, you can do something like this:

```
Gender: <select name="gender"> 
    <option value=" "> Not Selected </option> 
    <option value="Male"<?=$_SESSION['gender'] == "Male" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Male</option> 
    <option value="Female"<?=$_SESSION['gender'] == "Female" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Female</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: God bless you Chirs, you just got me the extra mark for my final assignment!

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty simplistic way to do this if you are using a form. Also, you probably want to use isset() in case it is the first time they visited the page.

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="male" <?php echo isset($_GET["gender"]) && $_GET["gender"] == "male" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="female" <?php echo isset($_GET["gender"]) && $_GET["gender"] == "female" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

All this does is insert "selected" into the option tag if the $_GET variable is set and the last one was that specific option. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You must read the database and add a php script like:

```
<option value="Male" <?php
if ($gender == "Male") { echo " selected"; }
?>>Male</option>
<option value="Female" <?php
if ($gender == "Female") { echo " selected"; }
?>>Female</option>
```