# how to create a multi-selection <select> element that will submit-on-click

Tags: javascript, submit, multi-select

I want an HTML [select] element that permits the user to make multiple selections simply by clicking (not by shift-clicking or control-clicking), AND I want the form to submit whenever they do so. I can achieve either of these behaviours, but not both. The code for the first behaviour appeared in

http://www.htmlforums.com/client-side-scripting/t-select-multiple-items-without-ctrl-117760.html

subsequently referenced on this forum at

[How to choose more than one option from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524462/how-to-choose-more-than-one-option-from-a-select-box)

and I have tried but failed to adapt the code to make the form submit whilst retaining the multi-select behaviour. Essentially, wherever I embed the submit(); it inhibits the multi-select (I presume simply by being executed first). Provoking a submit via some other control retains the multi-select, so it is not posting back to the server that is losing the selections. I tried adding a line to the addSelect event

```
function addSelect(id)
{
  var sel = document.getElementById(id);
  addEvent(sel, 'click', whichElement);
  addEvent(sel, 'click', addRemoveClicked);
  addEvent(sel, 'click', doSubmit);
}

function doSubmit(e) {
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

The form submits but doesn't retain the multi-select behaviour.

I tried adding onchange, onclick and even onmouseout to the declaration of the [select] element, but with the same result.

I confess that I don't fully understand how the JS originally provided by Paul Nelson works, so I don't know what else to try - can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messing with the user interface behaviors of the select element may not be the best call here. I'd suggest a different approach : use of a list of checkbox+label elements instead. You can easily adapt the ui to your need (hiding the checkbox if so desired, changing background color  etc...).

Js libraries/plugins exists for such a need, checkout for example http://loudev.com/

Comment: I'm generating my select box from code, so this should be relatively straightforward to implement as an alternative. I was excited by asm00's suggestion but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that's not a very good idea to mess with the "standard" or native way in which elements are handled by the browser.

That said, you can set a timeout function to trigger submitting the page once a given amount of time has passed. You can also check that the select has at least one selected element (to prevent submitting with no values).

So, each time you click the select element, a new timeout function is created (and the old one discarded).

You need to define a global variable to hold the timeout function in order to be able to abort in case a new click is made over the select element before page submits.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeoutObj;
</script>
```

And then:

```
function addSelect(id) {
    var sel = document.getElementById(id);
    addEvent(sel, 'click', whichElement);
    addEvent(sel, 'click', addRemoveClicked);
    addEvent(sel, 'click', doSubmitOnTimeout);
}

function doSubmitOnTimeout(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutObj);
    if (document.getElementById(this.id).selectedIndex > -1) {
    timeoutObj = setTimeout(function(){
        document.forms[0].submit();        
    },2000);
}
```

This code will submit your page 2 seconds after the last click over the select element.

**Update:**

I used the code you mentioned in your question to achieve multi-selection without holding down the "ctrl" key.

An alert will trigger 2 sec after your last click, only if there's something selected, showing you the indices of the items selected.

If you want to run it yourself, make sure you add the JS in between  tags inside the  of your test page or better yet, use a separate .js file and reference itfrom the  tag.

**2nd Update:**

I think you are a bit confused on some of the different concepts involved in the form submission process.

Whenever you submit a form, it is send to the server (to the target specified in the **action** attribute) using either one of these 2 form submission methods (specified in the  **method** attribute): GET or POST.

You can read about the difference of these two in the link I've added in the comments.
As a rule of thumb though, GET is used when not a change in the state of the site is expected, for example when someone is requesting something from your site. POST is used when a user is somehow affecting the state of your site with the form (for instance, when you sign up or place an order on a website's page). IMHO, if you always go with a POST method, you cannot be wrong.

Regarding your problem, which by the way I cannot seem to fully understand yet, let me point out some notes:

1. Regardless of what server-side platform you are using (be it PHP, Java, ASP.NET or other), when you submit the form the information is sent to the server and the target page (the one in the **action** attribute) is loaded.
2. In the example I've provided, I'm using the same page so after the form is submitted the very same page loads. Since I'm using plain HTML + javascript (thus no server side logic), once the page re-loads, the previously selected items are lost because the page is loading "from scratch", as the first time.
3. If you wanted to preserve the state of the selected options after page reloads, you need to do that by doing some server-side programming. Something as [explained here should get it done if you are using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072305/drop-down-list-keep-previous-selected-value-in-php).

Now, once you've worked out part 3, you should be able to have your page reload after the form is submitted and the items you had selected before submitting the form should then be preserved. At this point, if you want to modify the list of selected items, you still need to update the javascript code in the sample page to allow it to keep track of items that are pre-selected (or selected by default if you will) when the page loads.

I've updated the example to contemplate just that. Here's the link to the new example: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ2BZ/1/ .

I've set this up so that 'option 2' is now a pre-selected option, so when the page loads option 2 is already selected. You can verify now that making changes in the selected items will correctly take that pre-selected option into account.

As an end note, I truly suggest that if you really have trouble understanding all that's going on here, you try to get your page working with a regular multi-select element (using the 'ctrl' key to select more than one at a time) and once you have it all working as you want it to, add this desired feature. Good luck! :)

Comment: I tried this but the problem remained - the form was submitted after 2 seconds, but the multi-select no longer happened.

Comment: could you be more specific on what you mean by "the multi-select no longer happened"? What didn't happen? After the page reloaded you mean?

Comment: Sorry. Multi-select behaviour does not happen at all - if the [select] options are A, B, C, and I click on B, B is selected and I see submission after 2 secs, with selection of B retained afterwards. But if I then click C, the selection of B is lost immediately (before submission). Can you post a working example of your suggestion?

Comment: @user1280840 I just updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: Ok, after reading your comment once more, I believe I got a better understanding of what your problem is. Your problem is that you are losing the selection of items once the page reloads after having submitted it, and you click on the "select" element to modify the current selection. Is that correct?. I'll get back into this issue today. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: the problem appears as soon as I make a second selection i.e. try to select more than one element - so yes, first click is OK, page reloads, then as soon as I click on a second element (before the second submission/reload), I lose the selection of the first element.

Comment: I think I have made a horrendous oversight - I haven't said that I am using PHP, (the stackoverflow reference I gave was PHP-based but I should have said this explicitly). To be honest I'm not sure I knew that forms could be submitted to an HTML target, albeit themselves, and I don't really understand what is going on when this happens? If I run your code as filename "a.html", with action="a.html", I see the multiselect behaviour but what does posting/submitting mean, or do? If I change the filename and action to "test.php", each click loses the previous selection as previously reported.

Comment: You can read about the differences between POST and GET form submission methods here: http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post

Comment: asm00, thanks for all your efforts but we just aren't understanding one another. I am familiar with the process of form submission, and server-side processing. The problem is that including a line in JS to submit the form when a menu option is selected inhibits multi-selection. Delaying submission with a timer does not help. Your example is not submitted for server-side processing using POST or GET, so the problem does not occur.

Comment: @user1280840, thank you for the clarification. I created a local site and realized that once you submit the page the selected values are not in the body of the request. Using fiddler2, I saw the selected options just didn't make it to the server. In my example, the problem was that the SELECT element doesn't have a `name` attribute. Please add a `name` to the `select` tag and give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the name attribute as you suggest, and made the following changes: (i) file renamed a.php (ii) action changed to a.php (iii) added document.forms[0].submit(); to the end of the myClick function. Only the most-recently clicked value appears in PHP's $_POST array so I had to add a hidden var to store the choices and populate it inside the loop in myClick - document.getElementById('strSelect').value += (i+1).toString() + ';'; - and use that to reset the values on postback but IT WORKS! Many thanks to you, asm00.